# Apollo Server - parse REST result in Connector, Resolver or Model

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am wrapping an older REST API service with an Apollo server. Calls to the REST service results in a JSON object that nests the payload 2 to 3 levels deep. For example:

```
{ 
  - MRData: {
      - CatTable : {
           - Cats : []
```

And to further complicate matters, the nesting pattern and node names are different for each resource endpoint. So my question is, since each resource result will need custom manipulation, where is the best place to do it: in the Connector, Resolver or Model.

**Connector**

If done in the Connector, then a custom method is needed for each resource. Seems like a lot of boilerplate.

```
public fetchCats(resource: string) {    
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(url, (err, resp, body) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(JSON.parse(body).MRData.CatTable.Cats)
        })
      })
  }
```

**Resolver**

The resolver method receives a promise but the result cannot be manipulated:

```
const allCats = (_, params, context) => context.cat.getCats()
.then((data) => { // to late to manipulate data here })
```

**Model**

The Model looks promising but not quite sure how to structure it:

```
public getCats() {
    const cats = this.connector.fetchCats('/cats.json');
    return cats;
  }
```

Apollo will be (more often than not) integrated with REST API's. I'm looking forward discovering the best way to handle this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would generally recommend doing the parsing in the connector, because they should abstract over the details of the backends. If connectors abstract over the backend, you should technically be able to switch out one backend for another when appropriate. For example you could switch from querying a REST API to sending queries directly to the database where it makes sense.

The consequence of this is that you'll need to build a new connector for every REST API, because no two REST APIs are the same.

Comment: You bring up a good point with the abstraction layer. So the solution will be to build a fetch() and fetchPage() for each resources type since this particular REST API creates a custom node names per resource.

Comment: Or better yet pass resource_type argument to fetch() - something like `fetch(url, resourceType)` and then create ENUMs like `CAT_TYPE="MRData.CatTable.Cats"` and `DOG_TYPE="MRData.DogTable.Dogs"` to sort out which parse structure to use for each resource.